# Simultaneously applying each element of a matrix to a function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply

I simulated three matrixes and hope to realize a function.

It is hard to explain this function but I think the folllowing code of FOR LOOP is nice and simple to interpret what I want to do.

```
A=matrix(1:10000,100,100)
B=matrix(2:10001,100,100)
C=matrix(3:10002,100,100)

for (i in 1:100) {
  for (j in 1:100) {
    print(min(C[B>A[i,j]]))
  }
}
```

However, in fact the matrix of each would be much much bigger, for example 1000 * 1000, resulting in a huge time consumption by FOR LOOP. I tried apply() in two dimension but it doesn't improve at all according to system.time().

```
apply(A, 1:2, function(x) print(min(C[B>x])))
```

I wonder if there is any way to optimize this function to make it faster, or in brief, to use each element of matrix A simultaneously.

Many thanks advanced!

Answer (score 0):

To make your example manageable and understandable I reduced the dimension of the matrix.

```
A=matrix(1:10,2,5)
B=matrix(2:11,2,5)
C=matrix(3:12,2,5)
```

Running your function gives :

```
for (i in 1:2) {
   for (j in 1:5) {
     print(min(C[B>A[i,j]]))
   }
}

#[1] 3
#[1] 5
#[1] 7
#[1] 9
#[1] 11
#[1] 4
#[1] 6
#[1] 8
#[1] 10
#[1] 12
```

We can use `sapply` to test this on every element of `A` and then if needed turn it in matrix with same dimension as that of `A`.

```
out <- sapply(A, function(x) min(C[B > x]))
dim(out) <- dim(A)

out
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    3    5    7    9   11
#[2,]    4    6    8   10   12
```